# Getting an error when setting and observing the data in swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Here is two function checkCurrentConversation and set Current Conversation. CheckCurrentConversation function will check the useremail is present in firebase if present it return the conversation array and setCurrentConversation used for set the data in conversation array. But when I calling this functions the error is like (Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'InvalidPathValidation', reason: '(child:) Must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']'').See the code below and screenshots.

```
func checkCurrentConversation(_ userEmail:String,completion:@escaping([[String:Any]]?) -> Void){
        database.child(userEmail).child("conversation").observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            if let currentUserconversaion = snapshot.value as? [[String:Any]]{
                completion(currentUserconversaion)
            }
            else{
                print("not getting the current conversation")
                completion(nil)
            }
        }
      
    }
    
    func setCurrentConversation(_ userEmail:String,_ con:[[String:Any]],completion:@escaping(Bool) -> Void){
        database.child(userEmail).child("conversation").setValue(con) { (error, dbRef) in
            if error == nil{
                completion(true)
            }
            else{
                print("not set the values in setCurrentConversation\(error?.localizedDescription)")
                completion(false)
            }
        }
    }
```

Firebase Structure:
[image]

Comment: In case you didn't know, each English sentence ends with the period.  Otherwise, one cannot tell the end of each one.  Capitalize the first letter of the first word on each English sentence.

Comment: The error is telling you that what you have in your userEmail parameter “must be a non-empty string and not contain '.' '#' '$' '[' or ']'”

Comment: @Faheem please be sure to redact your database's address in the image you included to prevent illegal reads and writes to your existing database.